# Is it safe to reinstall with a Google prompt linked to my account?

Tags: google

I might put LineageOS on my phone, but I currently depend on it to perform two-factor [authentication prompts](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/7026266) for my Google account. Should I take any precautions to preserve access to my account?

Comment: Yes, of course. You can turn off two-step authentication temporarily, then set it up again on your "new" OS. You should also generate a set of one-time use passcodes to allow access (and keep them safe somewhere), which you really should have generated the first time you setup two-step authentication. You should also have one (or more) account recovery methods setup. These things should be done period, even if you don't change anything on your phone.

Comment: I already have backup codes and TOTP from an external device configured, so I suppose I'm good to go!